# Create a Dynamic Dashboard using Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-charting

I am creating a dashboard but the filter criteria of report that I am using is changing every time. 
So I decided to create a dynamic dashboard using Visualforce page.

I tried to create a visualforce page using Google chart but a funnel chart and similar meter gauge was not present. Also the charts were not having same look and feel like our salesforce.

So, is their any way to create a dynamic dashboard. Where I can change my filter criteria according to the user selected value and get a refreshed dashboard with different chart and values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Visualforce Charting components?  There's no funnel chart, but there are lots of other good chart types.  You feed these charts whatever data you want (from a SOQL query of your choosing) and voila.  They work very well for our needs.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_charting.htm

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a good way to do this would be to use Visualforce charting along with the Analytics API. The Analytics API allows you to run reports from Javascript and then process the results for display in a chart or some other manner.

The best bit is you can also update filters on the reports before requesting data, so using that you'll be able to make sure the data is correct for the person viewing the page. One word of warning there though (this cost me a few hours), you can't just submit the metadata for the updated filter. You first have to grab the metadata for the report (provided by a call in the API), change the part you care about, and then send it all back when you make the call to run the report.

[You can find the online documentation for the API here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using classic VF pages, then you can:

1. Use [Remote Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects.htm)
2. Use [APEX REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm)

If you are also thinking migrating to Lightning then you can

1. Use [Rest API in Lightning Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_api_calls_platform.htm)

Once you got the restful data, use any 3rd party [jstable](https://www.dynatable.com/) and [chart](http://www.chartjs.org/) liberay to create your dynamic dashboard